# Preprocessing stage & multiple files (basics)

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have three files and want to compile it.

The first file is app.c

```
#include"sum.h"
int main (void)
{
    sum();
    return 0;
}
```

The second files is sum.h

```
#ifndef SUM_H
#define SUM_H
void sum ();
#endif
```

and the third file sum.c

```
#include"sum.h"
void sum ()
{
return;
}
```

and I write these statements:

```
#ifndef SUM_H
#define SUM_H
...
...
...
#endif
```

to prevent the multiple definitions of the content of `sum.h`.

During compiling the `app.c` will enter the preprocessing stage and then `sum.c` enter the preprocessing stage my question when the `sum.c` enters how the preprocessor know that `SUM_H` is defined in the last file of myapp? 
I think that each source file enter the preprocessing stage and compiling stage individually.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, each file is compiled separately and hence include guards only **prevent multiple inclusion of a header file in the same** [**translation unit**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c) **and not across different translation units**.

When `app.c` is pre-processed by the pre-compiler only checks if `SUM_H` is already defined within `app.c` only. This avoids `sum.h` from being included multiple times through different headers in this present translation unit only. This is because as soon as `sum.h` gets included once `SUM_H` will be defined.